# Why Count query fetch documents?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document MongoDB like this:

- collection array of objectId
- one bool for draft
- one bool for  deleted

Exsample:

```
"_id" : "55689be772ba931a30c87fd8",
"Draft" : false,
"Deleted" : false,
"productsId" : [
    ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf5"),
    ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf8"),
    ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf0"),
    ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edee")
]
```

I have an index:

```
db.getCollection("mycolection").createIndex({ "Deleted": 1, "Draft": 1, "productsId": 1 }, { "name": "_deleted_draft_productsId" })
```

Why when I execute this query:

```
db.mycolection.explain("executionStats").count({productsId: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'),Draft: { $ne: true }, Deleted: { $ne: true } })
```

I receive this stats with `totalKeysExamined:687`:

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 685,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 3,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 687,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 685,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "FETCH",
            "filter" : {
                "$and" : [
                    {
                        "$nor" : [
                            {
                                "Deleted" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "$nor" : [
                            {
                                "Draft" : {
                                    "$eq" : true
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            "nReturned" : 685,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 687,
            "advanced" : 685,
            "needTime" : 1,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 7,
            "restoreState" : 7,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "docsExamined" : 685,
            "alreadyHasObj" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                "nReturned" : 685,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 687,
                "advanced" : 685,
                "needTime" : 1,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 7,
                "restoreState" : 7,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "productsId" : 1,
                    "Deleted" : 1,
                    "Draft" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_productsId_deleted_draft",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "productsId" : [
                        "productsId"
                    ],
                    "Deleted" : [ ],
                    "Draft" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "direction" : "forward",
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "productsId" : [
                        "[ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'), ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4')]"
                    ],
                    "Deleted" : [
                        "[MinKey, true)",
                        "(true, MaxKey]"
                    ],
                    "Draft" : [
                        "[MinKey, true)",
                        "(true, MaxKey]"
                    ]
                },
                "keysExamined" : 687,
                "seeks" : 2,
                "dupsTested" : 685,
                "dupsDropped" : 0,
                "seenInvalidated" : 0
            }
        }
    }
```

but if I try to remove `draft` and `deleted` bool fields this way:

```
db.Redazionale.explain("executionStats").count({IdProdotti: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4') })
```

I get this stats with `totalDocsExamined:0` that is what I expected also in previous query

```
"executionStats" : {
        "executionSuccess" : true,
        "nReturned" : 0,
        "executionTimeMillis" : 0,
        "totalKeysExamined" : 690,
        "totalDocsExamined" : 0,
        "executionStages" : {
            "stage" : "COUNT",
            "nReturned" : 0,
            "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
            "works" : 690,
            "advanced" : 0,
            "needTime" : 689,
            "needYield" : 0,
            "saveState" : 5,
            "restoreState" : 5,
            "isEOF" : 1,
            "invalidates" : 0,
            "nCounted" : 689,
            "nSkipped" : 0,
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "COUNT_SCAN",
                "nReturned" : 689,
                "executionTimeMillisEstimate" : 0,
                "works" : 690,
                "advanced" : 689,
                "needTime" : 0,
                "needYield" : 0,
                "saveState" : 5,
                "restoreState" : 5,
                "isEOF" : 1,
                "invalidates" : 0,
                "keysExamined" : 690,
                "keyPattern" : {
                    "productsId" : 1,
                    "Deleted" : 1,
                    "Draft" : 1
                },
                "indexName" : "_productsId_deleted_draft",
                "isMultiKey" : true,
                "multiKeyPaths" : {
                    "productsId" : [
                        "productsId"
                    ],
                    "Deleted" : [ ],
                    "Draft" : [ ]
                },
                "isUnique" : false,
                "isSparse" : false,
                "isPartial" : false,
                "indexVersion" : 2,
                "indexBounds" : {
                    "startKey" : {
                        "productsId" : ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4"),
                        "Deleted" : MinKey,
                        "Draft" : MinKey
                    },
                    "startKeyInclusive" : true,
                    "endKey" : {
                        "productsId" : ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4"),
                        "Deleted" : MaxKey,
                        "Draft" : MaxKey
                    },
                    "endKeyInclusive" : true
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

## Update

I uploaded a file dump to ricreate a small part of the whole database.
[click here to download](http://comunicandomultimedia.com/dump/test.zip)

and try those queries:

```
db.Redazionale.explain("executionStats").count({ IdProdotti: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'),Draft: { $ne: true }, Deleted: { $ne: true } })

db.Redazionale.explain("executionStats").count({ IdProdotti: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4') })
```

Comment: Because you did not exlcude `_id` via projection. Despite it's appearance `.count()` is not actually it's own method, but rather is a "cursor modifier". So `.find({ productsId: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'),Draft: { $ne: true }, Deleted: { $ne: true } },{ "_id": 0, Draft: 1, Deleted: 1, productsId: 1  }).count().explain()` should tell you something that looks a bit different.

Comment: This is actually covered in the documentation ['Covered Query'](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/query-optimization/#covered-query) and it does specifically say that fields not in the current index ( such as `_id` in this case ) **must** be excluded within the projection, otherwise "index coverage" is not possible. So I can understand the confusion when applying `.count()` by not understanding what the method actually is. But again, it actually is all documented.

Comment: Probably really should have made that clear as `.find(query,projection).explain()`. And even to look at `db.Redazionale.count` without the brackets `()` to see what is actually being invoked, and realize it just wraps the regular `.find()` and adds the cursor option for `.count()`

Comment: @NeilLunn, I believe the question is why it uses IXSCAN-FETCH instead of  COUNT_SCAN stage. The later does not require any projection. The covered query does not apply, since `productsId` is an array

Comment: @have a look if it falls under https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-17148. Could you also add `serverInfo` part.

Comment: @AlexBlex: "serverInfo" : {
  "version" : "3.4.7",
  "gitVersion" : "cf38c1b8a0a8dca4a11737581beafef4fe120bcd"
 },

Comment: Must be a typo, but the created index name is `_deleted_draft_productsId` while execution stats reads `"indexName" : "_productsId_deleted_draft"`. Not that it makes much difference tho. I am more curious why your execution stats doesn't have COUNT stage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that queries like `Draft: { $ne: true }`are actually range queries with following bounds:

```
"Draft" : [
    "[MinKey, true)",
    "(true, MaxKey]"
]
```

so your query results with 3 bounds:

```
           "indexBounds" : {
                "productsId" : [
                    "[ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'), ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4')]"
                ],
                "Deleted" : [
                    "[MinKey, true)",
                    "(true, MaxKey]"
                ],
                "Draft" : [
                    "[MinKey, true)",
                    "(true, MaxKey]"
                ]
            },
```

and it is up to the optimiser to pick the most selective index, if you have more than one.

In your case it decided the `productsId` is the most efficient one, which is a fair choice. It uses `productsId` part of the compound index `_productsId_deleted_draft` to fetch relevant documents, and then filter them by other 2 fields.

Removing 2 of 3 ranges allows to use COUNT_SCAN. So does converting boolean ranges to exact comparison. The query like

```
db.mycolection.explain("executionStats").count({
    productsId: ObjectId('55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4'),
    Draft: false, 
    Deleted: false 
})
```

Does COUNT_SCAN as one would expect using following bounds:

```
            "indexBounds" : {
                "startKey" : {
                    "productsId" : ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4"),
                    "Deleted" : false,
                    "Draft" : false
                },
                "startKeyInclusive" : true,
                "endKey" : {
                    "productsId" : ObjectId("55688d7a72ba931bf430edf4"),
                    "Deleted" : false,
                    "Draft" : false
                },
                "endKeyInclusive" : true
            }
```

The problem is that `Draft: { $ne: true }` is equivalent to `Draft: false` only if all of your documents has the `Draft` field, so it might be an option to ensure the boolean fields are always there. May be even enforce it with [document validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document-validation/). It really depends on how much benefits the optimisation brings.

Comment: This is the expected result, but the field draft or deleted are present in all documents, is this a bug?

Comment: No, it is not a bug, it is how `$ne` works. If you absolutely sure all your documents have (and will have in the future) these fields, you can replace `$ne: true` with `$eq: false` to do COUNT_SCAN. It works because boolean fields have only 3 states, and will not work with other data types.